# Symfony 4 php unit test - no tests executed

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

In my symfony 4 application I try to run the first unit test from the symfony [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html). But it returns the follwing message.

```php
    // tests/Util/CalculatorTest.php
    namespace App\Tests\Util;

    use App\Util\Calculator;
    use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

    public class CalculatorTest extends TestCase
    {
        public function testAdd()
        {
            $calculator = new Calculator();
            $result = $calculator->add(30, 12);

            // assert that your calculator added the numbers correctly!
            $this->assertEquals(4, $result);
        }
    }
```

> PHPUnit 5.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Time: 17 ms, Memory: 2.00MB
>
> No tests executed!

And when I try to run that test directly using following command it also gives following error.

```
$ ./bin/phpunit tests/Util/CalculatorTest.php
```

```php
    #!/usr/bin/env php
    // tests/Util/CalculatorTest.php
    namespace App\Tests\Util;

    use App\Util\Calculator;
    use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

    public class CalculatorTest extends TestCase
    {
        public function testAdd()
        {
            $calculator = new Calculator();
            $result = $calculator->add(30, 12);

            // assert that your calculator added the numbers correctly!
            $this->assertEquals(4, $result);
        }
    }
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPUnit\Runner\Exception: Class 'tests/Util/CalculatorTest' could not be found in '/home/username/server/tests/Util/CalculatorTest.php'. in /home/username/server/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:102

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: check if you are running correct php unit. Not sure about symfony 4, but in symfony 3, i had to use the phpunit from vendor dir. It was getting mixed up with the globally installed phpunit that failed to detect symfony's unit test configurations.

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas I also tried that too. But still same result. I also edit the question to display error when I try to directly run that test.

Comment: if the namespace is `App\Tests\Util` and the classname is `CalculatorTest`, why does it try to find the class: `tests/Util/CalculatorTest`? You have an autoloading problem.

Comment: it was a silly mistake. i forgot to add the <?php :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution for me was add a phpunit.xml config file in the root directory of my project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Regards